# Appcelerator Titanium Webview rendering issue loading local HTML files

Tags: webview, titanium, rendering, appcelerator

in my app I use webview with many local HTML files. When the app is running over Android version 4.4.X or newer, the performance of scroll worsened and the text selection ceased to function properly. Looking for a solution, I saw that to solve this problem the Appcelerator docs recommend to set borderRadius property to a value greater than zero (the problem is associated with rendering on Chromium). Indeed, when I set borderRadius to 1, the scrolling performance is better and the text selection works well, but the quality of text (pixel) worsened and the users are complaining rightly. I'm using Titanium SDK 5.0.2GA and 23 platform API. I tried too using 5.2.2GA and 5.3.1GA but with the same results. I spent many hours to find a solution but without success. Please, someone can help me? I have been desperate. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to open that WebView link in external browser in your device and see if it is really the Titanium causing the issue or is it that website url?

Comment: Thanks, Prashant. But when I open local HTML file using Android native browser the page open very well. I tested using Genymotion emulator.

Comment: I am not sure about Genymotion as I always use devices for Android to save time and weird issues. So I will suggest you to test your code on atleast 2-3 devices because it could be an issue with resolution. If it does not help, then please share some part of code which can help us to see the issue.

Comment: Prashant, many thanks to try help me. `webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
   html:content, // content of a local HTML file
   autoDetect: [],
   backgroundColor:'transparent',
   scalesPageToFit:false,
   enableZoomControls:false,
   borderRadius: 0
  });`

Comment: See this sample: http://cascubo.com/iliturgia/Sample.html

Comment: can you try setting ***scalesPageToFit : true*** and ***borderRadius : 1*** ?

if it does not help, then I think it's something related to your local html file designs as there are chances that your html file does not behave well according to the applied CSS or UI strategies. 

So, you can do some test to make sure your local file is correctly designed, that try to grab some code from internet and test it on your desktop browser by scaling window or in your device browser and then through Titanium and see what makes the difference in comparison to your local file.

Comment: Thanks, Prashant. Setting scalesPageToFit to true or false produce the same result. I'll try test with other HTML files. Again, thank you.

Comment: it can be your local file then.

Comment: I tested it with several local files, including one with only <html> <body> Testing </ body> </ html>. The results were the same. I do not believe the problem is the local files.

Comment: I found the problem and solution. In tiapp.xml, in the tag <manifest>, there were parameter android:anyDensity with value to "false". When I changed to "true", the scroll of webviews became very quick. In other hand, I needed to change all app's interface because this change caused change of all UI reference. But, after many hours of adjusts, finally the app is OK. Thanks.

Comment: great..you can post it as an answer for future references.

Comment: Sure. I will. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and solution. In tiapp.xml, in the tag manifest, there were parameter android:anyDensity with value to "false". When I changed to "true", the scroll of webviews became very quick. In other hand, I needed to change all app's interface because this change caused change of all UI reference. But, after many hours of adjusts, finally the app is OK. Thanks.